# Type '(err: any) => void' has no properties in common with type 'QueryOptions' on Node route

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I have the following route in a Node controller that is giving me an error that prevents Node from running

```
public async deletePost(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const deletedPost = await BlogPostModel.findByIdAndDelete(id, err => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).send.send('Error deleting post');
      }
    });

    // needs to send error if post not found (400 status code)

    res.status(200).send(deletedPost);
  }
```

I get an error for the `err => {` section of my code saying:

```
Type '(err: any) => void' has no properties in common with type 'QueryOptions'
```

I don't fully understand this error, but it sounds like its requiring I type out the argument in the error handling callback function. However, I've also tried `(err:any)=>` and that doesn't work as well. Would anyone be able to fill me in on how to correctly use a callback function for error handling here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the second argument must be of type `QueryOptions`, but you pass a function instead

It's not how you should handle errors, you can't mix promises and callbacks

```
public async deletePost(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    const deletedPost = await BlogPostModel.findByIdAndDelete(id);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send.send("Error deleting post");
  }

  res.status(200).send(deletedPost);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the request wont hang in case deletedPost == null ?

Comment: @Sardar it will send status 200 with value `null`